# Disable href after one click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to disable an html link after one click.
I found some solutions but it seems that they doesn't work on my code.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function image(url) 
{
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    var url = "http://www.luigimelisi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/url_routing.jpg";
    img.src = url;
    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
}
function clickAndDisable(link) 
{
    link.onclick = function(event) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="image"></div>
<div><a href="javascript:image();"onclick="clickAndDisable(this);">Click Here</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you clarify as to what the problem is? Is the link not working even the first time, or is it always working?

Comment: It is always working, every time I click it shows the image and I want to show it only at first click then disable the link. Sorry for my english

Comment: Do not disable the anchor, just delete it or hide with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

In your clickAndDisable function and the onclick handler, the event (in this case 'e') is not being passed as a parameter. You pass in 'event' but reference 'e'. You can make this work by changing 'e' to 'event'. This is what your code might look like for that to work:

```
link.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code will work in the way you are hoping. You just made a typo. The mistake you made is in the function 'clickAndDisable' you handle an event by passing in a parameter 'event', but then you try to utilize the event by calling e.preventDefault.

to fix, change `e.preventDefault()` to `event.preventDefault()`

Here is the working code or test on JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/y6ktL4af/

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function image(url) 
{
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    var url = "http://www.luigimelisi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/url_routing.jpg";
    img.src = url;
    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
}
function clickAndDisable(link) 
{
    link.onclick = function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="image"></div>
<div><a href="javascript:image();"onclick="clickAndDisable(this);">Click Here</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this by removing the `href` property of the `a` tag, and then modifying the `clickAndDisable()` function to do something like:

```
link.onclick = null;
image();
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible method would be to change the `onclick` statement in the `a` element to something like:

```
onclick="this.href=''"
```

This changes the `href` of the hyperlink to nothing, so nothing happens when the link is clicked on. It also obviates the need for the `clickAndDisable` function. Is that what you mean by disabled?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this with disabling or hiding the link but a reusable one would be to attach an event handler to all links that should be clicked only once:

```
var oneClickEls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-allow-one-click="true"]');

var _i, _len, _el;
for ( _i = 0, _len = oneClickEls.length; _i < _len; _i++ ) {
  _el = oneClickEls[_i];
  _el.hasBeenClicked = false;
  _el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hasBeenClicked) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    this.hasBeenClicked = true;
  });
}
```

This will allow us to specify which links should only be clicked one in the html by adding an attribute named `data-allow-one-click`:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething();" data-allow-one-click="true">Click Here</a>
```

Here is a js fiddle showing your code working: https://fiddle.jshell.net/1akdp6sp/